# Formula for conditional expectation wrt to probability-zero event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, definition, conditional-expectation

Let $W$, $S$ be two independent, continuos r.v., both in $L^2$. Let $P = g(W,S)$ a certain function of both $W$ and $S$; moreover, $P$ is continuous and in $L^2$.

Let $l,k: \mathbb R\mapsto \mathbb R$ two continuous functions such that $l(W), k(S)$ are also in $L^2$.

I am interested in computing

$$E[l(W)k(S) \mid P = p]$$

My idea was to condition on $W = w$ and integrate wrt to the density of $W$, i.e. writing

$$E[l(W)k(S) \mid P = p] = \int_{\mathbb R} l(w) \ E[k(S) \mid g(w, S) = p] \ f_W(w) dw$$

This would help because I can compute $E[k(S) \mid g(w, S) = p]$.

But is the formula correct? Intuitively I think it should be, as $W$ and $S$ are independent, but I am a little confused about the definition of conditional expectation wrt to a probability zero event. The definition I encountered weren't so precise (usually just saying "use the density instead of the probability"), so I am not sure how to determine if the formula is correct or not (and how to fix it!)

Hints/references are also appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Generally you can just use the density as long as the density is continuous at the relevant points. But in general these kind of issues are taken care of by using the $\sigma$-algebra definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: @Ian We can assume that the density is continuous. How does that help in solving the first expectation? Or are you saying that the formula I wrote is valid? Also, it's not intuitive to me how to go from the sigma algebra definition of conditional expectation to a conditional expectation defined on events, and then to probability-zero events

Comment: Er no, what I meant by "use the density" was to use the division by the sum of the values of the density of $P$ on the event $P=p$, just as you would usually divide by the probability that $P=p$. As for the $\sigma$-algebra definition, $E[l(W) k(S) \mid \sigma(P)]$ is a $\sigma(P)$ measurable random variable. Consequently it has the same value for any $\omega_1,\omega_2$ such that $P(\omega_1)=P(\omega_2)$. So you essentially just plug in any $\omega$ with $P(\omega)=p$ to calculate your desired quantity. The issue is actually calculating the $\sigma$-algebra version in the first place.

Comment: @Ian So you mean writing $$E[l(W)k(S) \mid P = p] = \int_{\mathbb R^2} l(w)k(s) \frac{f_{W,P}(w,p) f_{S,P}(s,p)}{f_P(p)} \ dw ds $$? The issue is that $f_{W,P}(w,p)$ is not so trivial to compute, that's why I was wondering if the formula I wrote is correct :)

Comment: I mean sure it works but it is just the total expectation formula for marginalization of $W $ (which I did not notice earlier, thinking you were doing something more complicated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of conditional expectation, $$E(\ell(W)k(S)\mid P)=h(P)$$ where the measurable function $h$ is such that, for every bounded measurable function $m$, $$E(h(P)m(P))=E(\ell(W)k(S)m(P))$$ that is, $$E(h(P)m(P))=E(\ell(W)k(S)m(g(W,S)))$$ or, equivalently, $$\int h(x)m(x)f_P(x)dx=\iint \ell(w)k(s)m(g(w,s))f_W(w)f_S(s)dwds$$ In particular, for every $p$, $$\int_{-\infty}^p h(x)f_P(x)dx=\iint \ell(w)k(s)\mathbf 1_{g(w,s)\leqslant p}f_W(w)f_S(s)dwds$$
By identification, this holds true if $$h(p)=\frac1{f_P(p)}\frac{d}{dp}\iint \ell(w)k(s)\mathbf 1_{g(w,s)\leqslant p}f_W(w)f_S(s)dwds$$ Thus, for $P$-almost every $p$, $$E(\ell(W)k(S)\mid P=p)=\frac1{f_P(p)}\frac{d}{dp}\iint_{g(w,s)\leqslant p} \ell(w)k(s)f_W(w)f_S(s)dwds$$ or, equivalently, $$E(\ell(W)k(S)\mid P=p)=\frac1{f_P(p)}\frac{d}{dp}E(\ell(W)k(S);g(W,S)\leqslant p)$$

---

**Edit:** Above, we exposed the correct approach to every similar problem of conditional expectations but this does not disqualify, a priori, the approach in the question. We turn to this problem now and, for this, we first rewrite carefully what the claim in the question entails.

The claim is that $$E(\ell(W)k(S)\mid P=p)=E(\ell(W)h(W,p))$$ where $$ h(w,p)=E(k(S)\mid g(w,S)=p)$$
hence the function $h$ is characterized by the property that, for $W$-almost every $w$ and for every measurable function $r$, $$E(k(S)r(g(w,S)))=E(h(w,g(w,S))r(g(w,S)))$$
Thus, the claim holds true iff, for every measurable function $m$, $$E(\ell(W)k(S)m(P))=E(q(P)m(P))$$ where $$q(p)=E(\ell(W)h(W,p))$$
No idea why this should be true... So, let us turn to an example: assume that $P=W+S$, then $g(w,s)=w+s$ hence $$h(w,p)=E(k(S)\mid w+S=p)=k(p-w)$$ One sees that the claim becomes that, for every measurable function $m$, $E(\ell(W)k(S)m(P))$ is simultaneously $$\iint\ell(w)k(s)m(w+s)f_W(w)f_S(s)dwds$$ and $$\iint\ell(w)k(p-w)m(p)f_W(w)f_P(p)dwdp$$ thus, one requires that $$\iint\ell(w)k(s)m(w+s)f_W(w)f_S(s)dwds=\iint\ell(w)k(s)m(w+s)f_W(w)f_P(w+s)dwds$$ which can only hold in full generality if the densities coincide, that is, after some obvious simplifications, if, for $W$-almost every $w$,  $$f_S(s)=f_P(w+s)$$ Well, at last we have a proof that the claim **does not hold**, right?

Comment: Thank you! So this is the way to proceed :) Can you point what goes wrong with what I did, i.e. just condition on $W = w$ and then integrate? P.S. Also, is there no immediate way to connect it to $E[k(S) \mid g(w, S) = p]$ (which is easily computed in my case? ) Thank you! :)

Comment: Sorry but your approach is unsound, please see edit.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification! It's very much appreciated :D